# Zend Framework Setup on Hostmonster?

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, upload, project, hostmonster

I have created a project locally using Zend Framework 1.11. I have spent a long time learning the basics of the framework from all the online tutorials I can find, and I now feel fairly comfortable using the ZF Tool and locally working on my project on WAMP. I decided it was time to upload my project and deploy it on my shared hosting server, which happens to be Hostmonster.

After uploading my project, I have been struggling to get it to function correctly on the remote host. I have successfully uploaded my Zend Framework Library and included it in my PHP.ini, and all tests show it is seen by the server.

My directory structure, which was originally created to the standard format by the ZF Tool locally on the command line, is not pointing to the same paths on the remote server, so everything was messed up when I navigated to the Project/public folder. After much more Googling, I found several posts by various bloggers related to modifying .htaccess files, etc., which resulted in all my other sites hosted on the server being disrupted.

The closest I have been able to come to re-creating my initial local site on the Hostmonster host is by:

1. Taking all the directories out of my "public" ZF folder, and putting them directly in the web root of my server, (public_html), and:
2. Changing the 'APPLICATON_PATH' of my index.php file from the ZF public folder with the path to my ZF library (changed to reflect where it is in relation to the new location).

With this (tedious) setup, I am now seeing my index view being rendered with all CSS and Javascript, but I am unable to navigate to any of the other views, and the form I have displayed via a view script is likewise not showing up, only the index view is rendered.
My Zend Framework Library is located in a directory in the web root-- public_html, with the php.ini adding it to the include path.

This is becoming very frustrating as I like a lot of the features of ZF, but the restructuring of the site is proving impossible. If anyone has instructions or experience with this setup, I would greatly appreciate it. I am also hosting multiple other sites on this server, so I'm hoping I don't have to change from the single php.ini configuration(5.3) I'm currently using or mess around with a bunch of .htaccess files.

Thanks for any help anyone may have!

Answer (score 1):

I have ZF running on HM no problem. Just place your index.php and .htaccess in your public_html dir, and what I did was created a `public_html/zend/library` folder and in my index.php including that library to get things working.

Also what do u mean you're running other sites off this server? Are you serving the application on the root of your domain? ie in your http://domain.com/ path? or different subdomains?

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like what I have done, and I can't figure out why only my index view is rendering, and all other views are having a 404 error. I think when I uploaded my site, there is a configuration(probably .htaccess) problem. What I meant by hosting other sites on the server, is that I have a few Wordpresses and a Drupal installation running on the the same domain in sub-folders. I am trying to serve my Zend Application from the root of the domain(Yes), but I am not clear on how to modify my my .htaccess so it will access my ZF project without disrupting my other sites.Thanks!

Comment: your htaccess file should allow direct access to any static file such as images CSS and Javascript , and your other sites, but redirect everything else to index.php

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I got it to work now, after moving my .htaccess file out to the public_html directory. Everything works now, except for some reason my contact form is not showing up in my layout(It is included via the view mechanism in my layout).

Comment: Ok -- I now have figured out the final problem why my contact form wasn't displayed. First, I was using the filter ->addFilter('HTMLEntities') on some of my fields, which I needed to change to ->addFilter('HtmlEntities') for the Linux server(case-sensitive). Also, the path to my Captcha image/font directory was broken. Now all is working, Thanks.